# Drupal 7 - add already existing block to LOGIN page

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I'm creating a website using Drupal 7. I want to add a very simple block that I have already created to the right sidebar of the login page. This block contains only HTML formatted text.

The URL for my login page is www.websitename/user/login/.

I have selected the radio button to display the block on specific pages only, and I've tried:

- login
- /login
- /user/login
- user/login

And anything else I could think of, but the block won't show up on that page.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> user/login

should work. Please be sure to select the correct region and under permission no role is checked, by default it should show for anonymous users!!

Comment: You're right, I had a permission issue that I completely overlooked. Wow. Thanks!